# How can I get initialize or startup time of PHP

Tags: php, time, startup

I want to know which files are used to initialize or start PHP before running/executing a PHP file.

Also, How can I calculate the initialization or startup time of PHP?(on local and server both)

Can anyone help me with it?

Comment: What for and why? Both things may not be possible without digging deeply into the PHP source code

Comment: You can use `strace` for the first question. Timing startup time will be inexact. (Might have to write a C program that does something akin to `time php -r "posix_kill(getmypid(), 9);"`. But that's super-wacky.)

Comment: @Pekka
I want to calculate the startup time so that I can compare it with another scripting language and based on that get some results of its performance

Comment: @mario
hey thanks for the help 
can you confirm me that if I can get PHP's startup time without using any other language?

Comment: is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` what your looking for? (I assume it's not)

Answer (score 1):

The Linux kernel provides the start time of a process in `/proc/<pid>/stat`; it is the 22nd field. It counts the number of jiffies since boot before the program was started. I believe the "jiffies" has been fixed at 100 / second for *many* versions now, though I can't name which specific one introduced it.

It's a little difficult to convert the time in jiffies since boot into a *useful* time, but that's all arithmetic.

`time(2)` returns the time in seconds since the epoch; divide your process's start time by `100` (or whatever the jiffies / second is on your platform) to get seconds since boot, subtract the one from the other to get the start time of your process in seconds since the epoch, and convert that to your favorite formatting as you need.

Comment: hey Is the solution possible using PHP?
and what about windows?

Comment: It sure can. Open `/proc/self/stat`, read the 22nd entry in the file, and start doing math. :)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to calculate the startup time so that I can compare it with another scripting language and based on that get some results of its performance

I don't think the interpreter's startup time is a useful metric for this comparison at all.

What you *could* do, for example, is set up two web servers with two different scripting languages, make a web request to a script that does some standard task, and measure the time until the first byte arrives. That might give you a somewhat realistic picture of each platform's performance.